# ld returned 1 exit status error

Tags: c++

I am writing a tester for a file HCTree.hpp that has a build() method but when I try to run the tester I get `

```
ld returned 1 exit status.
```

What is the problem?
Here is the tester:

```
int main()
{
  HCTree pt; // Edit fixed from HCTree* pt

  vector<int> vec (256,0);
  vec[0] = 1;
  vec[1] = 3;
  vec[2] = 2;

  pt.build(vec);   
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which is it, C or C++? It doesn't make sense to use both tags. And show how you're compiling and linking the program, since that's where the problem probably is.

Comment: @Barmar it's C++ (I edited). C doesn't have templates.

Comment: @Barmar ah, just got your comments. :) Okay, no enough details is given in that case. OP - can you post the full error code?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: The "undefined behavior" can create an error message which looks suspiciously like a linker error although I haven't seen this happen.

Comment: An example of your link line in your makefile will substantially increase the odds of an applicable response to your question. And you had *better* have read Luchian's answer before it was removed, because this code has a blatant invalid pointer dereference (unless `build` is a static class function of `HCTree`, and I *highly* doubt that).

Comment: Okay I changed the code and it is complaining that I didn't implement the distructor there were several error in the include files that I fixed so can't reproduce the error message

Comment: @WhozCraig I did read the code and made that change, but I was working on the code so couldn't give any more info until now

Comment: Okay after writing the destructor and fixing bunch of errors and discrepancies in the #include files everything compiled.  Thanks.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Hello Grijesh could you help me out with something? I am really interested in a post that recently got deleted by the user.  It says however that it is available to moderators and users with over 10000 rating.  I was wondering if you could see if you could post the contents of that post for me via email.  I really wanted to read that post and saved the link so I could read it when I had time but was dissapointed to find it got deleted.  Here is the link to it:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419969/c-dijkstra-implementation-with-map-container
Thank you so much,
Kevin